# Overflow lis to next line within a fixed div?

Tags: css, list, html, overflow, fixed

I have a fixed div with a ul inside of it. The fixed div is set to `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: scroll;`, each li is set to `float: left;`. When there are too many li to view in a line, I want them to overflow to the next line, but it continues in a straight line to infinity, never breaking into the next line. The lis are generated by a JavaScript script.

Here is the link to the page: http://hypotheticalmeraki.doubleohnine.com

Edit: on the bottom left, there's an up arrow, when you click that, the fixed div comes up. The images in that are each an li.

Thank you so much

**Issue Fixed**
Made the ul a fixed width (made it !important) and set `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Comment: Can you set a fixed width on the ul, and set the ul to overflow:auto? I can't see the part of your site where this occurs.

Comment: I tried a fixed ul, 600px, and setting it to auto, but it still doesn't make a diference... the div appears with you click the up arrow on the bottom left.

Comment: Nevermind, I made the width value !important and it works perfectly now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div1> <- fixed, overflow
<div2> <- position relative
<ul><li>
</div2>
</div1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto;` instead of using `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y: scroll`